# How did I reach nearly a million people?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious as to how exactly I have reached 823K people? That seems an incredible amount for only 35 answers and 31 question.

Any further details on how the people reached tab is calculated would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The way in which the "People Reached" statistic is calculated is described in [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534). One of its many flaws is it includes the views of a question you answered that happened *before you answered*. (Stack Exchange do not have a way of breaking down that view count by time period, so this is what they went with.)

Your answer to [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/34670) is the main contributor to your People Reached number. That question has about 730,000 views as of now.

You can see the view counts of the questions you answered [in Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/cooking/query/59366/my-most-viewed-answers-based-on-question-view-count?userId=18910). Note that not all of these count toward People Reached; since the answer must pass certain conditions stated in the post I referenced.

Comment: It's a little... interesting that answers to community wiki questions count, too. I guess that one in particular is a single-author answer, so it's not inaccurate in that sense, just the time period of the views and sharing among answers as you mentioned.